# Node regex pattern to extract version and filename

Tags: node.js, regex

I need help with a regex expression to extract the name and the version from a filename string eg:

```
"ABC V1.2.3+4.exe"
"file name with spacesV1.2.3+4.exe"
"etc...V1.2.3+4.exe"
```

the version part is always in the format `VX.Y.Z+B` but the name (anything before 'V' can be anything)

I was able to extract the version number with this regex pattern:

```
/V(\d+)(\.\d+)(\.\d+)(\+\d+)?/g (build number is optional)
```

For example:

```
let file = "HelloWorld V4.5.6+7.exe"; 
console.log(file.match(/V(\d+)(\.\d+)(\.\d+)(\+\d+)?/g));

output: [ 'V4.5.6+7' ]
```

So far so good. but I also want the part from the start of the string till the matched version number.

I want the output to be:

```
['whatever is before the matched version number', 'V4.5.6+7']
```

I'm not so good with regex and I've spend 4 hours trying.

Comment: You could use a non greedy match for any character using a dot `.*?V(\d+)(\.\d+)(\.\d+)(\+\d+)?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.*` to match everything before the version number. Put capture groups around the prefix and the version parts of the regexp.

Don't use the `g` flag. That makes it return all the complete matches, rather than an array of capture groups. Since there can only be one match, there's no need for the global flag.

```js
let file = "HelloWorld V4.5.6+7.exe"; 
console.log(file.match(/^(.*)V(\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?:\+\d+)?)/));
```